# SharePoint 2010 SP1 and CU in SharePoint Server(Enterprise)

Tags: administration, service-pack

We planned to apply SharePoint 2010 SP1 and CU for SharePoint Server(Enterprise).

Is it necessary to install SharePoint 2010 Foundation SP1 before applying SharePoint 2010 SP1 for SharePoint Server?

Please share recommeded Orders/Steps for applying SharePoint 2010 SP1 and June CU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is recommended to apply the foundation packages before the SP 2010 SP1.

Please refer to the following link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2011/06/29/sharepoint-2010-sp1-and-the-june-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [Service Pack 1 (SP1) for SharePoint Foundation 2010 and SharePoint Server 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221773) white paper describes the features that are included in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1). In addition, this paper provides some guidelines you can follow so that your solutions work with current and future versions of SharePoint Foundation 2010.

- [Deploy software updates for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263467.aspx)

You should update SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1 before updating SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 for best practice perspective. I learn this from a few SharePoint experts.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to understand that Office Web Applications and Project Server if applicable also need to be updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following order:

1. Foundation SP1
2. Foundation Language Pack SP1
3. Foundation June CU
4. SharePoint Server SP1
5. SharePoint Server Language Pack SP1
6. SharePoint Server June CU
7. Office Web App SP1

Comment: Thanks for you input and proceed the same and was succesfully installled

Comment: You can vote for answers that have been helpful by clicking on the arrow. The answer that solved you question best can be marked as "Answered". Thank you